# Full width tables for written data

Tags: tables

I know there is tonnes of full width table questions here and there and I hope this isn't considered a duplicate, but I need to have this table and write out answers for organic chemistry lab and can't seem to stretch out the columns.

Any advice is appreciated or point me in the right direction.  By the time I graduate I reckon I will have this full sorted out!

**Preamble**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

**Table**

```
% There are two more below this but the one should give me a grasp for the others

\section*{Data Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
               & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Test}}                                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Density/Solubility} &     \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Flammability}      \\ \hline
Compound           & Observation  & Conclusion               & Observation &     Conclusion               \\ \hline
Cyclohexane        &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             &     \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Cyclohexene        &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             &     \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Toluene            &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Unknown \#           &              &                          &             &                          \\ \hline
Unknown \#           &              &                          &             &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: What I have now]

Essentially the table width now is 10.5 cm.  I like for it to stretch an additional 8 cm so there is room for me to write in all cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `tabularx` ensures full width. The `makecell` package allows for line breaks and a common formatting of cells, in particular the default placement of the contents is vertically and horizontally centred:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
% There are two more below this but the one should give me a grasp for the others

\section*{Data Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|*{3}{X|>{\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Test}} \\
\cline{2-5}
\multirow{-2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Density/Solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Flammability} \\
\hline
Compound & \makecell{Observation} & \makecell{Conclusion} & \makecell{Observation} & \makecell{Conclusion} \\
\hline
Cyclohexane & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
\hline
 Cyclohexene & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
 \hline
 Toluene & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
 \hline
 Unknown \# & & & & \\
 \hline
 Unknown \# & & & & \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I expected!  Anyway to get observation, conclusion... centred?  Density/Flammibilty I saw the l and made it c, but adding `{c}` didn't seem to work.  Though playing around I just realised that adding `\hspace{5em}` might have achieved similar results...didn't think whitespace would had worked to be honest...

Comment: The simple way is to use the `\makecell` command (from `makecell` package: it allows for a common formatting and line breaks inside cells. Please see my updated answer, if it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `p` column type to dictate the column width. The parameter is the width of the column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
% There are two more below this but the one should give me a grasp for the others

\section*{Data Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
               & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Test}}                                                            \\ \cline{2-5} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Density/Solubility} &     \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Flammability}      \\ \hline
Compound           & Observation  & Conclusion               & Observation &     Conclusion               \\ \hline
Cyclohexane        &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             &     \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Cyclohexene        &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             &     \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Toluene            &              & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &             & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\ \hline
Unknown \#           &              &                          &             &                          \\ \hline
Unknown \#           &              &                          &             &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]